# Monitorar caixa de entrada de E-Mail

Tags: vb.net, email

Gostaria de uma função para monitorar a caixa de entrada de E-Mail.

Comment: Tem algo  mais específico que você queira? Precisamos de mais informações para ajudá-lo. Nós podemos ajudar respondendo dúvidas aos problemas que você tenha. Mas não somos repositório de funções prontas.

Comment: eu gostaria de criar um processo que vai ficar monitorando a caixa de entrada da conta de E-Mail, assim que um novo e-mail for recebido ele ira exibir uma pequena mensagem no canto da tela tipo o Messenger.

Comment: Coloque esses detalhes na sua pergunta para facilitar que todos possam entendê-la mais facilmente. Edite quantas vezes for necessário. http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/700/como-comecar-aqui-no-stackoverflow-em-portugues

Comment: Deixe claro em que tipo de ambiente você precisa desenvolver isso... especificar ambiente, linguagem, framework ajuda a atrair de quem poderia ter a resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Em geral, caixas de e-mail tem acesso via o protocolo "POP3". Infelizmente, e para minha surpresa também, não encontrei no Framework uma implementação "padrão". Geralmente isso já vem pronto.

Por sorte,  existem algumas implementações abertas por aí. Não utilizei nenhuma delas, mas vale a pena checar se são projetos maduros e confiáveis:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/hpop/
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15611/POP3-Email-Client-with-full-MIME-Support-NET-2-0

Comment: valeu vou dar uma olhada